# How do I reconcile all these different formulas for the standard error of the difference between means?

Tags: standard-error

I'm trying to make sense of the different formulas I see for the standard error of the difference between two (sample) means. I'm struggling to reconcile the different formulas. All formulas below use this notation:

[image]

Formula 1 and Formula 2 below are given by David C. Howell. Formula 3 and Formula 4 are provided by Noel A. Card. And Formula 5 is provided by Richard Berk:

[image]

As far as I can see, Formula 2 is just the result of an algebraic manipulation of Formula 1. And I think Formula 3 is the result of an algebraic manipulation of Formula 2. What I'm confused about is how Formulas 4 and 5 come about. Card uses the "roughly equals" (i.e. the squiggly equals) sign to link Formula 3 with Formula 4, suggesting that Formula 4 may not be the result of an algebraic manipulation. **Can somebody explain how we get Formula 4 from Formula 3?**

Also, I note that Berk's Formula 5 looks very similar to Card's Formula 4, but with a difference I can't understand. The denominators appear to be the same. Card has "N total" whereas Berk has "n1 + n2" but these amount to the same thing. However, the numerator in Formula 5 is the pooled standard deviation, but the numerator in Formula 4 is two times the pooled standard deviation. **Can somebody explain why there's a difference in these numerators**?

Finally, **can somebody explain how we get Formula 5?**

Thanks so much for your help!

Best Wishes

Adam

Comment: (1), (2), and (3) seem superficially the same. Speaking for myself, I need more information about source and context of (4) and (5).

Comment: Yes - I think 1, 2 and 3 are just algebraic re-expressions of one another. I've been told that Berk may have made a typo or inadvertently omitted the "2" from the numerator of Formula 5. So that would mean it's the same as formula 4. Formula 4 comes from Card's book on meta-analysis. He links Formula 3 to Formula 4 by the "roughly equals" sign but I have no idea why they should be roughly equal